# Common mode voltage suppression for low side high bandwidth current sensing

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, common-mode

I want to measure current of short duration high amplitude pulses using a low side shunt resistor. The test pulses are up to 400ns (2.5Mhz) with amplitude up to 3000V, depicted in the picture below.
[image]

Ideally, the shunt resistor should be referenced to the ground and the voltage drop should be in mV range across the shunt resistor. But, due to different factors (noise, EMI, cable resistors e.tc.), shunt resistor is getting high common mode voltage.
I checked online, there are some amplifiers with high common mode voltage value, but these amplifiers have low bandwidth, mostly up to 500KHz.
So, My question is, what is the best way to get ride of common mode voltage without effecting the shunt resistor desired signal.

Comment: How did you measure that common mode voltage i.e. what was your circuit that monitored the resistor?

Comment: In what way does the common mode noise pose a problem?

Comment: 400ns pulses do not correspond to 2.5Mhz. They will contain harmonics into the tens of megahertz, all of which you must amplify equally if you wish to retain squareness. And you need to do that with an amplifier of tens or more of gain. I think the least of your problems is common-mode anything, or noise. What's your current setup, that is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Andyaka I paced 0.01 Ohm resistor and measure the voltage drop across it using an oscilloscope. I know that the cable, connector will change the voltage reading, but, in this test I was just testing the the peak voltage, which was very big.

Comment: @LordTeddy The voltage drop across the sense resistor has big spikes. Which may damage the circuit.

Comment: @SimonFitch Amplifier has the ability to deal with harmonics. So, currently this is not a problem.

Comment: If you can see the voltage across the resistor, then it's not common mode.